# Semiconductors extrinsic and intrinsic carriers concentrations equations

Tags: semiconductor-physics, carrier-particles

I understand why $n \cdot p = n_i^2$ holds for intrinsic semiconductors, but why is that the equation also holds true in the case of an extrinsic semiconductor?

Here, $n$ is the charge density of the negatively charged particles, $p$ is the density of the positively charged particles and $n_i$ is the carrier concentration.

How is it proved mathematically?

Comment: Detailed balance still holds.

Comment: This relation is valid only when the semiconductor is in thermal equilibrium with the surrounding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Semiconductor - the mass action law question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541244/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Semi conductors (holes and electrons)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227078/) (This contains more explicit derivations than the duplicate proposed above.)

Answer (score 0):

This is identical to the issue of pH in water, with $n$ and $p$ replacing H+ and OH-.

See this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water

To expand this answer as per a request in the comments:

So the questioner understands why $n$ $\cdot$ $p$ $=$ $n_i^2$ for intrinsic semiconductors.
With an extrinsic semiconductor one need only assume that all of the dopant atoms are ionized.  At all but the lowest of temperatures this will be true.  With this assumption in mind, the carrier concentration equation is undisturbed.  The carriers created by the dopant are just as effective at extinguishing the minority carriers as are the naturally occurring carriers of an intrinsic sample.

Comment: Could you expand it in more details? As now it is a *link-only answer*, and the article linked does not really answer the question.